# Does shape dynamics introduce a temporal order on events separated by a space-like interval such that their simultaneity is not relative?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, time

I've read some popular books and articles that reference shape dynamics (e.g., The Singular Universe and the Reality of Time, https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/article/shape-dynamics/). I have also attempted to familiarize myself with the underlying maths to generate my own clarity (via https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/theoretical-physics/msc/dissertations/2020/Joshua-Hoffmann-Dissertation.pdf), but I am not confident in my understanding. What I really want to make sure I understand is whether shape dynamics introduces a temporal order on events separated by a space-like interval such that their simultaneity is not relative or if the order relation on events as per York/cosmic time permits such relative simultaneity within its own framework.

Comment: Your question could be improved by giving some specific references.

Comment: Barbour's books related to his cosmological model include "The End of Time" and the more recent "The Janus Point", widely available thru interlibrary loans.  As a procrastinator who naturally favors a past- AND future-eternal view of reality as more plausible than that "creation from nothing" one which many Yank physicists are trying to hang onto, I find his substitution of gravity for the subtle obscurity of Boltzmann's entropy (whose directionality has conflicting interpretations) very hopeful, although, as Barbour is primarily a mathematician, background in that field might help.

Comment: More on [shape dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22shape+dynamics%22).